# Embarcadero TCategoryButtons: prevent DoReorderButtons

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++builder, vcl

Im developing a software in Embarcadero C++ Builder 2006 which uses the component "TCategoryButtons". This component gives me the possibility to reorder the buttons (TButtonItem). Whenever I do this, it triggers the event OnReoderButton and DoReorderButton. I don't remember the exact sequence.

My question is: is there how to prevent the button reordering in some cases without disabling the AllowReorder property? Can I access the method DoReorderButton (which seem so be protected)? What im looking for is a way to disable the reordering if the button comes from or goes to an specific position. Would be glad if anyone could help me, or give me an idea how to do such thing.

Comment: What is wrong with disabling `AllowReorder` in those situations, then re-enabling it later?

Comment: @caps I was intending to use this feature while dragging a TButtonItem. Thus, depending on the position that the user is hovering the TButtonItem, I would perform a check to block/allow the user to place it there (and display it visually). If I disable the AllowReorder before dragging, I'm not able to start a drag and drop operation. If I disable it during run time, the dragging operation is canceled, and the current TButtonItem being dragged is back to it's place, which I would still like to have in dragging mode.

Comment: @caps Anyway, my workaround was to write my own drag and drop procedure, performing the allow/block checks depending on the X and Y position, and calculate between which TButtonItems the user is trying to leave the one being dragged. Thought its kind of flickering :c